# Assign row value to button

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to assign database row value to button, so when I press delete or edit, it affects only that specific row. At the moment $personData[0] is row ID.
Here is little piece of my code which creates table with data and buttons.

```
<?php if (!empty($dataArray)) : foreach ($dataArray as $person) { ?>
            <?php $personData = explode(";", $person); ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $personData[0]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $personData[1]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $personData[2]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $personData[3]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $personData[4]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $personData[5]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $personData[6]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                    <form method="POST">
                    <button name="btnEdit" value="" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                    <button name="btnDelete" value="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php } endif; ?>
```

Comment: add a hidden input to send with the form. `<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $personData[0] ?>">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add the value to the buttons themselves, but simply to the form.  A hidden field will do fine:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $personData[0]; ?>" />
    <button name="btnEdit" value="" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
    <button name="btnDelete" value="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Then when the form posts you can check the value of `$_POST['id']` for the identifier in the form being posted.